# How to test function out of scope and this in AngularJS Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to apply testing to a particular controller.

Testing this controller is ok:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
    $scope.password = '';

    $scope.grade = function () {
        var size = $scope.password.length;
        if (size > 8) {
            $scope.strength = 'strong';
        } else if (size > 3) {
            $scope.strength = 'medium';
        } else {
            $scope.strength = 'weak';
        }
    };
});
```

But I'd like to test:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {


    var vm = this;
    vm.password = '';

    function grade() {
        var size = vm.password.length;
        if (size > 8) {
            vm.strength = 'strong';
        } else if (size > 3) {
            vm.strength = 'medium';
        } else {
            vm.strength = 'weak';
       }
   };
});
```

I tried to test the controller using the code below:

```
describe('Test', function () {

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var MainCtrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('PasswordController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('Should not throw Exception', function () {
        scope.password = 'abc';
        var call = function () {
            MainCtrl.grade();
        }
        expect(call).not.toThrow();
    });
});
```

But I get this error :         *Expected function not to throw, but it threw TypeError: 'undefined' is n
ot a function (evaluating 'MainCtrl.grade()').*

This [stackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401371/testing-a-controller-not-using-scope-using-karma) help me to apply testing to function inside 'this'. But I want to test functions out of $scope and 'this'...

Any Idea how to apply unit testing to this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grade method is not being attached to the controller;

```
vm.grade = grade;
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gHHW4x28BJpO0lQXC6kO?p=preview)

Comment: I think the OP intentionally kept the method "private". Making it public just for the sake of testing it does not sound right to me.

Comment: If you want to test it directly, it must in some way be exposed. If it is called from another action from within the controller, that can be verified. For example, if you had a watcher on vm.password that executed the grade method, you would be able to verify the strength property is what it should be after a digest.